# IBM Worklight - How to debug an application?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I view my Worklight developed website or pages in Google chrome? I want to inspect element for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised answer based on comments:**
Make sure that you are using an external browser (in your case, Chrome) to preview the application. You can do that in Eclipse via Preferences >> Browsers.

Please also read the following training module: [Debugging your application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_04_Debugging_your_applications.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Idan Adar, I tried but in Worklight console -> **Preview as common resources** link:

It opens page in some browser without browser's address bar and tool options. 

- How do i Add Chrome to add in: **Preview as common resources** link

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens to you, but that doesn't matter. Did you try RIGHT-CLICKING on an element and choosing "inspect element"?

Comment: yes i tried, its using IE...i want to use Chrome as Eclipse's default browser

Comment: Now I understand... you need to change your Eclipse settings to use an EXTERNAL BROWSER. Preferences >> browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. I working now, thanks for your kind suppport.

Answer (score 1):

**For debugging a worklight app in google chrome** 
    right click on project--> open worklight console--> right click on browser's properties-->copy the url and paste it into chrome's address bar. 
By using this you, easily see the worklight developed page on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Open Worklight Console

Under Mobile Web >> 'Click on Get App URL'

Run the app url in any browser